# Excel to return a value in a cell after checking a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I have a range of cells; for simplicity say three columns A1:A3 containing either the letter P, M or D. I would like to be able to check this range of cells and display in cell A4 either P, M or D depending on the frequency of the letters (see below for example of intended results). Need all cells as D to result in D. Its to track student grades, Pass (lowest denominator), Merit and Distinction.

PPP = P; PMP = P; MPP = P; PPM = P; MMM = M; MDD = M; MMD = M; DMM = M; DDD = D; PMD = P

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3,"P"),"P",IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3,"M"),"M","D"))
```

[image]